# Can someone please tell me how to make a bootable USB-Stick with UbuntuStudio 19.10 Eoan Ermine?

Tags: boot, usb

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04.6 LTS as the OS. I want to install  Ubuntu Studio 19.10 Eoan Ermine on this laptop which is the Asus Eee PC with USB 2.0.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 19.10 reaches EOL (*end-of-life*) next month (2019-October + 9 months), so I'd start Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (2020-April release which is also a *long-term-support* release), however ensure they'll boot on your box.  Not all eeepc's are amd64 capable, x86 ones won't use later than 18.04 LTS (with exception of 18.10/19.04 which are both now EOL)

Comment: The Asus Eee PC may not be able to properly run recent versions of ubuntu due to its low memory and processing power. I suggest you use a very lightweight OS like Lubuntu, Linux Lite or Puppy Linux. If you don't have plans to connect it to internet often, you can use an older version of Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which would be even more faster.

Comment: Which model of eeePV is it? Which CPU? How big is the internal drive? The answer to these questions decide what advice to give about which version and flavour of Ubuntu that works. So please help us help you by answering these quextions.

Answer (score 0):

In your case maybe you can't run that Linux for Eee PC, but anyways, To make a bootable flash disk:

**Command line version:**

you need to plug your flash disk into your laptop and then run `sudo mount` to see
which device is related to it (for example it can be /dev/sdb or something else)

```
dd if=Your_.iso_of_UbuntuStudio of=/dev/sdX bs=4M conv=fdatasync status=progress
```

again you need to change the X with the thing you saw in `sudo mount` output

---

**GUI Version:**

there are some apps that helps you to make a bootable flash disk with your distro:

**unetbootin**
https://unetbootin.github.io/

**Etcher**
https://www.balena.io/etcher/

---

*As a note*, there are other applications for this purpose, you can always search on google like this `name_of_the_application alternativeto` then you will find a great site called https://alternativeto.net/ that helps you find alternative software that are free or open source.